# Indent a code listing in LaTeX

Tags: listings, indentation, article

For a little LaTeX document I am writing I would like to insert source code fields (in SQL) into my paper.

I found out that I can use the listings package for this, which works well so far:

```
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}

\usepackage{listings} 
\lstset{numbers=right, 
                numberstyle=\tiny, 
                breaklines=true,
                backgroundcolor=\color{light-gray},
                numbersep=5pt} 
\lstset{language=SQL}
```

This works well so that I can insert code listings like:

```
\begin{lstlisting}{insert}
INSERT INTO Tabelle (Spalte1, Spalte2, Spalte3) VALUES (Wert1, Wert2, Wert3);
\end{lstlisting}
```

What it shows me are light-gray boxes containing the code, but they start at the beginning of the line, just like the text. I now would like to have code listings automatically being **indented a bit**. So that the gray box doesn't start at the level of the text.

Can anybody tell me how to achieve this? I am quite a beginner at working with LaTeX... would be great if anyone could help!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `listings` package allows you to change the margins (see section 4.10 of the [documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf).)

```
\lstset{numbers=right, 
                numberstyle=\tiny, 
                breaklines=true,
                backgroundcolor=\color{light-gray},
                numbersep=5pt,
                xleftmargin=.25in,
                xrightmargin=.25in}
```

Adjust as necessary.

Comment: THank you very much! This works perfectly! Didn't know it allows this attribute...

Comment: documentation link took me to a scary place...  Found this instead: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf

Comment: @Vegar Thanks for noticing the scary link :o. I've updated it with your much safer one.

Answer (score 16):

You can do this using the `xleftmargin` option of `listings`. See the manual page 33, section 4.10 "Margins and line shapes".

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}

\usepackage{listings} 
\lstset{numbers=right, 
                numberstyle=\tiny, 
                breaklines=true,
                backgroundcolor=\color{light-gray},
                xleftmargin=\parindent,
                %xleftmargin=1cm,
                %xrightmargin=\parindent,
                numbersep=5pt} 
\lstset{language=SQL} 
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{lstlisting}{insert}
INSERT INTO Tabelle (Spalte1, Spalte2, Spalte3) VALUES (Wert1, Wert2, Wert3);
\end{lstlisting}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```